# Cannot understand recursive doubling in this context

Tags: recursion, parallel-processing, hpc

I am struggling with a recursive doubling problem I was assigned. I understand that recursive doubling breaks up a bigger problem into smaller sub-problems so that the computation may be parallelized, but I don't think it is doable with this question.

> Exercise 1.4.  The operation
>
> for (i) {
>       x[i+1] = a[i]*x[i] + b[i];
>   }
>
> cannot be handled by a pipeline because there is a dependency between
>   input of one iteration of the operation and the output of the
>   previous. However, you can transform the loop into one that is
>   mathematically equivalent, and potentially more efficient to compute.
>   Derive an expression that computes x[i+2] from x[i] without involving
>   x[i+1]. This is known as recursive doubling. Assume you have plenty of
>   temporary storage. You can now perform the calculation by
>
> • Doing some preliminary calculations;
>
> • Computing x[i],x[i+2],x[i+4],..., and from these,
>
> • Compute the missing terms x[i+1],x[i+3],....
>
> Analyze the efficiency of this scheme by giving formulas for T0(n) and
>   Ts(n). Can you think of an argument why the preliminary calculations
>   may be of lesser importance in some circumstances?

So I understand the expression for x2 would be: x2 = a1(a0*x0+b0)+b1
but what I do not understand is A. how this relates to recursive double ... and B. how this would achieve any speedup if the result of the previous calculation is still needed.

Answer (score 1):

The central concept is that once you can compute x[i+2] in terms of x[i], a[i], and b[i], you can then split into two threads:

1. Start with x[0] and compute the even-numbered terms.
2. Compute x[1] from x[0], then compute the odd-numbered terms.

In fact, if you have good insight into your parallelization overhead, you can generate a Fibonacci tree of processes, a new one starting each time a previous thread gets going nicely.